# RedirectMatch in mod_rewrite doesn't work as expected

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm driving crazy about this, but I'm sure it's only a small thing..

All I'm trying to do is redirecting https server traffic to another website in my virtual hosts config file:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
  ServerName somewebsite.ch
  RewriteEngine on
  RedirectMatch 301 ^client$ https://someotherwebsite.com/client
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/client$ https://someotherwebsite.com/client
</VirtualHost>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, it looks like the page tries to load the content of the other website, but the Adress Field in the browser still shows the old URL, and the browser body is empty..

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a slash at the end? Your config won't match, for example, /client/

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/client/$ https://someotherwebsite.com/client
```

If the URL continues after *client*, you could do this:

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/client(.*)$ https://someotherwebsite.com/client$1
```